# printf: NetBeans VS Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, printf

I'm having a hard time here:

I'm using Eclipse (Indigo SR2) to code my Java programs. I'm a newbie in Java but I know this is well written, as it is (almost the) same as in C:

```
int number = 2;
System.out.printf("The number is:\n%02d",number);
```

So, this should be the output:

```
$ The number is:
$ 02
```

Despite of that Eclipse is throwing me this error message:
*"The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)"*

I found it weird because I had already executed this line of could in another IDE.
So I tried (copy-pasted) it onto NetBeans and it worked just fine!

Since we're talking about the same language, there's gotta be something wrong here, right?

Comment: What Java version is Eclipse working with? Indigo is not too new, as Kepler is already out.

Comment: It's working on Java SE7, I missed setting the compliance to the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the Java Version. it should not be less than 1.5. This printf method was added in **JDK 1.5**  only

Java Compiler - change your compiler compliance and ensure you are using a JRE of that version or higher